# problem with parsing numbers using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a Javascript file that calculates and parse the rows in a crm module called jobs.

I have function called recalculateSummary that calculate the price like this 
[I want it to show 3,578.00 in total like Line Total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvM0m.png)

The problem is the function `parseFloat` i think it ignores the ',' as i want if i write 3,578.00 the total should be 3,578.00.
I was able to achive this by removing parseFloat function and removing the ReplaceAll function but i got error when i add more rows the total value becomes 0.00.

```
    recalculateSummary: function(){

    var subtotal = 0;

    $.each($('.row_line_total'), function(index,value){
        lineTotal = $(value).html().replaceAll(',','.').replaceAll('&nbsp;','');
        subtotal += parseFloat(lineTotal);
    });
```

i know the question isn't clear but i need some help

Comment: Using punctuation makes reading easier

Comment: Well, you're right, the question is not clear. Unfortunately, that makes it very difficult to help. Can you please narrow your code to just the part you are having an issue with? With a sample of the HTML it acts on (if any)? See [mcve] for tips. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Are trying to add `toFixed(2)` for calculation result?
I mean this:

```
$('.summary_subtotal').html($.number(subtotal,2));
```

->

```
$('.summary_subtotal').html($.number(subtotal.toFixed(2),2));
```

Comment: i tried it but i still get https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvM0m.png
what i want to get instead is https://ibb.co/txLwqK9

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that by replacing the comma with the dot, `parseFloat` will interpret that as the decimal separator and so your number suddenly is a factor of 1000 smaller.

Take for example 3,578.00

1. Your code will grab that value as a string with `$(value).html()`.
   This is OK, although it would be better to do `$(value).text()` as
   you are not really interested in HTML encoding, but plain text.
2. Then the code performs a disastrous replacement with
   `.replaceAll(",", ".")`. This will turn the string to "3.578.00"
   (Not good!).
3. Finally the code converts this string to number with `parseFloat`.
   The first dot is interpreted as decimal separator, not as thousands
   separator (which it originally was). The second dot cannot be
   interpreted as part of the number, and so `parseFloat` returns a
   number with value 3.578. You probably have some other mechanics in
   place to only display 2 decimal digits, so this value ends up on the
   page as 3.58 (rounded).

In order to fix this problem, replace this:

```
lineTotal = $(value).html().replaceAll(',','.').replaceAll('&nbsp;','');
```

with:

```
lineTotal = $(value).text().replace(/[^.\d]/g, '');
```

Here we remove anything that is neither a dot (`.`), nor a digit (`\d`), using a regular expression: `[^.\d]`. So now the example value will become "3578.00" (the thousands separator is removed). `parseFloat` will turn this string into the number 3578. Your rendering mechanics will possibly render that with two decimals and a thousand separator as 3,578.00

All in all it is better to write your logic based on numeric variables and only use the DOM elements for output, not to read values *from* it (which are already formatted).

Comment: wow thank you very much it worked !!
but can you explain more to me why it worked ? in more detail if you can
thank you very much

Comment: I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much you are awesome That's a perfect answer